# How can I implement LinkedIn Cognito login/signup without getting redirected to Cognito/Auth0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, auth0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to add LinkedIn login to my React app that's using Amazon Cognito. I did everything as explained in the [Amazon docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-linkedin-auth0-social-idp/) and it works *but* I'm not using Amazon Cognito hosted UI and I don't want my user to get redirected to Auth0 site to login with LinkedIn.

Is there any way to implement LinkedIn Cognito login\signup without getting redirected to Cognito/Auth0? Or maybe there is already a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Official answer from amazon support:

> After investigating this further, and reaching out to the Cognito
>   Team, I can confirm that the intended functionality is not currently
>   possible with Cognito. The required State parameter is stripped from
>   requests when added manually, preventing the flow from being bypassed
>   like this. After researching this further it looks like there is
>   already a feature request for providing a workaround and I have noted
>   your desire for this functionality as well.
>
> Unfortunately at this time I can't confirm any ETA regarding this
>   request.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained as impossible without Auth0. Good question. LinkedIn's OpenID is just different than [FB and Google](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html)'s public login which Cognito accepts right now. I don't have code that authorizes a Cognito Pool with LinkedIn's OpenID. I believe I found the document that will explain what's missing in LinkedIn's OpenID in detail: [How do I set up LinkedIn as a social identity provider in an Amazon Cognito user pool?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-linkedin-auth0-social-idp/) I wouldn't throw away the [Sign in with LinkedIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin) OpenID service in your app. It's just that Auth0 is absolutely necessary unless [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/) changes its OpenID.

Comment: I know that Auth0 is necessary. The only problem I have is that I cant do the auth without the Auth0 login screen. I want my users to stay in my app and get redirect to LinkedIn only not to Auth0 and then to LinkedIn

Comment: Sounds a lot simpler for the user to login to LinkedIn alone and skip Auth0. I hope somebody finds code to do that I don't have it.

Comment: Do you end up paying twice? Ie both Auth0 and cognito MAUs?